# Как создать такую подсказку в яндекс карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Вот макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы при клике на балун появилась подксазка "5 соток" и рядом белый блок с контентом.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для добавления подсказок (хинтов) и всплывающих окошек (балунов) API Яндекс.Карт предлагает использовать [макеты](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/templateLayoutFactory-docpage/?from=SO). [Вот тут целая статья в руководстве пользователя](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/layouts-docpage/?from=SO).

В вашем случае шаги будут такими:

- описать макет для хинта метки с нужным дизайном
- описать макет балуна метки с нужным дизайном, тут может быть сложнее, т.к. у вас в балуне фотографии и много всего.
- указать ваши кастомные макеты для объекта клика, например, метки.

Также, теоретически можно балун с фото показывать отдельно от API'шных сущностей. Тогда для него вы просто верстаете html-объект, который по клику показываете где-то над картой.